# Change second drop down list depending on first drop down list and third drop down on second dropdown selection using php and arrays

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

i am getting two drop down example but i want three drop down example

the first drop down value is selected the second should change and after second drop down 3rd should change and then person will click save it will go to mysql database

please give me any example
i got one but its for 2 drop down

I already tried this code but its not the write code because if i chnge first DD rest two also changes

```
           ( http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nQBK2/)
```

## HTML:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="1">Item 1 second</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2 second</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3 second</option>
</select>
<select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value="1">Item 1 third</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2 third</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3 third</option>
</select>
```

## JQuery:

```
var $select2 = $('#select2'), $select3 = $('#select3');
$("#select1").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();

    if ($select2.data('options') == undefined) {
        $select2.data('options', $select2.find('option').clone());
    }
    var options = $select2.data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $select2.html(options);

    if ($select3.data('options') == undefined) {
        $select3.data('options', $select3.find('option').clone());
    }
    var options = $select3.data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $select3.html(options);
});
```

Comment: While including `jsFiddle` link to your question is a good practice, it is recommended that you include relevant parts of your code inside your question body, as `jsFiddle` tends to go down often, making answering your question impossible.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/nQBK2/3/

Comment: @Altaf Kadu can you say if the above fiddle fixes your problem so I can put as the answer? :)

Comment: @Edward in the given example whenever i select first DD the other two dd also changes but actually i want first dd will change second dd and after selecting second third will change

Comment: Ok, you need to be clearer what you are trying to accomplish when you ask questions on here. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you asked by selecting the options by their value:
The filter function you were using was removing all the option apart from the one that was selected.

`find('option[value="' + i + '"]');`

http://jsfiddle.net/nQBK2/4/

```
select1 = $('#select1');
select2 = $('#select2');
select3 = $('#select3');

$(select1).change(function() {
    var i = $(this).val();
    $(select2).find('option[value="' + i + '"]').prop('selected', true);
});

$(select2).change(function() {
    var i = $(this).val();
    $(select3).find('option[value="' + i + '"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: thanks i got it now @edward